# How to stack social icons

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm having a brain fart. I apologize if this question has been answered before, but I don't really know developer lingo so I'm not sure what to type in.

I have built my own social icons, which will sit on the right of the screen. Currently, I'm using a seperate class for each icon with height: number vh; to make them stacked on top. I'm sure this isn't the correct way. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Here is my current code:

```css
.fa-facebook {
  background: purple;
  opacity: 0.5; 
  color: white !important;
border: 2px solid white; 
}

.fa-twitter {
  background: purple;
  opacity: 0.5;
  color: white !important;
border: 2px solid white;  
}
/*social*/
.fa-social {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px; 
}
  p.social {
  position: fixed;
  right: 13px;
  top:30vh;
  text-align: center;
 font-weight: 800;   
 } 
 .fa-social-1{
    top:35vh;
 }
 .fa-social-2{
    top:45vh;
 }

.fa:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

```html
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        

<a style="text-decoration: none;" target="_blank" class="fa fa-social fa-social-1 fa-facebook"></a>
<a style="text-decoration: none;" target="_blank" class="fa fa-social fa-social-2 fa-twitter"></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best not to use fixed position for the items individually - better to put them in a container, position that and let the browser handle the layout.

```css
.fa-facebook {
  background: purple;
  opacity: 0.5; 
  color: white !important;
border: 2px solid white; 
}

.fa-twitter {
  background: purple;
  opacity: 0.5;
  color: white !important;
border: 2px solid white;  
}
/*social*/
.fa-social {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  right: 10px; 
}
.fa:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
}
#social-container{
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    top:35vh;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        

<div id="social-container">
    <a style="text-decoration: none;" target="_blank" class="fa fa-social fa-social-1 fa-facebook"></a>
    <a style="text-decoration: none;" target="_blank" class="fa fa-social fa-social-2 fa-twitter"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox. It will clean up most of your css.

```
<div class="social-group">
  <a style="text-decoration: none;" target="_blank" class="fa fa-social fa-social-1 fa-facebook"></a>
  <a style="text-decoration: none;" target="_blank" class="fa fa-social fa-social-2 fa-twitter"></a>
</div>
```

Css..

```
     /* Only CSS */

.fa-facebook, .fa-twitter {
  background: purple;
  opacity: 0.5; 
  color: white !important;
  border: 2px solid white;  
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
}
  /* Extra CSS */

  .social-group {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin-top: 30vh;
  }

.fa:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

Working example

https://jsfiddle.net/khvrLyon/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add padding in the  Tags, here is an example:

```
   <a style="text-decoration: none; padding-bottom: 10px" target="_blank" 
   class="fa fa-social fa-social-1 fa-facebook"></a>

   <a style="text-decoration: none; padding-top: 10px" target="_blank" 
   class="fa fa-social fa-social-2 fa-twitter"></a>
```

If this does not work try:

```
 <div class="container" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
 <a style="text-decoration: none;" target="_blank" class="fa fa-social fa- 
 social-1 fa-facebook"></a>
 </div>

 <div class="container" style="padding-top: 10px;">
 <a style="text-decoration: none;" target="_blank" class="fa fa-social fa-
 social-2 fa-twitter"></a>
 </div>
```